# Get all monthly values to follow the same % distribution curve in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to figure out if there is a formula that uses to the first two rows to give me the values in the “Total” row below without having to create the waterfall in between. Basically the “added each month” row is considered to be the first month of that value and then that value needs to follow the distribution curve in row 6.

[image: Table image]

Unable to create a formula that will do this calculation without having to create the waterfall

Comment: Please provide more details about what is your input and the output you expect. Try to provide a minimalist sample. Put the sample data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format. Copy your data from excel, then generate the table and copy it back to your question leaving a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

This would work regardless the excel version you may have.
Use this in `E21` and drag to the right:
`=SUM(E9:INDEX(E:E,COLUMN()+4))`

It sums the current column from row 9 up to row the the row number of current column # + 4 (for column E that means 5+4 = row 9, column F 6+4 = row 10, etc.)